# Calculate power of 2 sided Z A/B test - pooled version

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power

I want to calculate the statistical power of a 2 sided A/B test where I have 2 groups of coin tosses (that is, from 2 different coins) and their respective successes. I want to test whether the two coins have different probabilities.

I'm following page 6 of https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Proportions.pdf, which follows the paper Chow et al. (2008) (I haven't found it online), and states that:

$$1 - \beta = Pr(Z <  \frac{z_\alpha \sigma_{D,p} + (p_1 - p_2)}{\sigma_{D,u}})$$

where:

$n_1$ and $n_2$ are the respective number of coin tosses.

$s_1$ and $s_2$ are the respective successes.

$p_1 = s_1/n_1$, $p_2 = s_2/n_2$.

$q_1 = 1 - p_1, q_2 = 1 - p_2$.

$\sigma_{D,u}$ is the standard unpooled error:  $\sqrt{\frac{p_1 q_1}{n_1} + \frac{p_2 q_2}{n_2}}$

$\bar{p} = \frac{n_1 p_1 + n_2 p_2}{n_1 + n_2}$, $\bar{q} = 1 - \bar{p}$.

$\sigma_{D,p}$ is the standard pooled error: $\sqrt{\bar{p} \bar{q} (\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})}$

and $z_\alpha$ *seems* to be the critical value.

I have no problems with the standard errors and I know I'm calculating them correctly. However, I know I'm not getting a correct statistical power as I compared my results to [this](https://abtestguide.com/calc/) tool and I'm getting other values.

I suspect I'm calculating $z_\alpha$ incorrectly. The book states the following:

*"Find the critical value (or values in the case of a two-sided test) using the standard normal distribution. The critical value is that value of z that leaves exactly the target value of alpha in the tail."*

I'm using $\alpha = 0.05$ (I want a confidence level of $0.95$). What value for $z_\alpha$ should I be using and why? **I don't understand how to calculate the $z_\alpha$ that this book describes. I don't understand if, it being a 2 sided test, I should be doing 2 calculations.**

For the record, let's assume:

$$n_1 = 81000$$

$$n_2 = 80000$$

$$s_1 = 1600$$

$$s_2 = 1696$$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the respective number of coin tosses with each coin, and $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the respective number of successes.

In this example, as far as I know, the correct power should be (according to an online tool), **83.13%**.

This it not for homework; I'm implementing a specialized open source tool and want to share it online.

Comment: Please define symbols that you are using and show formulas for $\sigma_{D,p}, \sigma_{D,u}.$ Questions here should be as self-contained as possible, not relying on users here to find and read relevant parts of a linked (possibly unreviewed) paper.

Comment: you are right, done

Answer (score 1):

Your notation, and thus details of your Question, are unclear.
Are $S_1$ and $S_2$ observed numbers of successes? If so, I
assume you have $n \approx 80\,000$ and want to to know power
of a test of $H_0: p = 0.20$ vs. $H_1: p\ne 0.20,$ at the 5% level
of significance, to detect differences of about $\pm 0.02.$

**Result from Minitab statistical software.** If all of that is true, then the following output from a 'power and sample size'
procedure in a recent release of Minitab may be relevant. This procedure
assumes equal sample sizes in the two groups.

```
Power and Sample Size 

Test for Two Proportions

Testing comparison p = baseline p (versus ≠)
Calculating power for baseline p = 0.02
α = 0.05

              Sample
Comparison p    Size     Power
       0.022   80000  0.796665

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]

> *Note:* There are many versions of tests for differences in binomial success probabilities in various statistical software packages, depending on
> whether a pooled or unpooled standard error is used, whether
> a continuity correction is used for a normal approximation, and
> other considerations. Especially using procedures in online sites,
> you need to know the details of the test for which the power
> computation is made.

**Simulation in R.** In R, I used a two-sided `prop.test` without a continuity correction (on account of
large sample sizes) to distinguish between
numbers of successes from $\mathsf{Binom}(81000, 0.019)$ and
$\mathsf{Binom}(80000, 0.021)$ at the 5% level. In 100,000 such tests
there were $81,769$ rejections. So the power of the test is about 81.8%.

```
set.seed(1117)
pv = replicate(10^5, prop.test( c(rbinom(1,81000,.019),
               rbinom(1,80000,.021)) , c(81000,80000), cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.81769
```

The first of these 100,000 tests led to rejection of $H_0$ with P-value $0.014 < 0.05 = 5\%,$ as follows:

```
set.seed(1117)
x1 = rbinom(1, 81000, 0.019)
x2 = rbinom(1, 80000, 0.021)
x1; x2
[1] 1500
[1] 1663


prop.test(c(x1,x2), c(81000,80000), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(x1, x2) out of c(81000, 80000)
X-squared = 10.759, df = 1, p-value = 0.001038
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.0036252315 -0.0009127315
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.01851852 0.02078750
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your answer, but I'm not looking for the statistical power of this particular example. My question (as I stated) is  the meaning of $z_\alpha$ at page 6 of the link and how to calculate it in the pooled version of a 2-sided A/B test.

Comment: I edited my question in an effort to make it clearer

Comment: Moreover, please notice that in my scenario I have an unequal sample size

Comment: Yes. You may have trouble finding software or an online calculator that accepts different $n$'s as input. The most powerful configuration is a balanced design. If the two $n$/s are nearly the same, then use the smaller for such procedures. If you can find a formula that works for the style of test you're using, then you can use different sample sizes. And (as above) you can use different sample sizes in a simulation.

Comment: This tool: https://abtestguide.com/calc/ accepts both n's, I think - and for what I am doing I would like to do the same